# Angular 6: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, input, runtime-error, parent-child

I have a really strange problem. I'm sending data from parent to child component with @Input, and I get this error but when I tried to print the value in ngOnInit, I got the correct value and not undefined.
The data in the parent is defined and I get the value in the console when I print the data in the parent and child component and I still get that error (even if I access the data)

**this is the screenshot of the error and the value I get from console.log**

[image]
[image]

relevant parent html:

```html
<quiz-course [quiz]="currentUnitQuiz"></quiz-course>
```

parent ts:

```js
export class CoursePlayComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  course: ICourse;
  courseId: number;

  // the current and prev quiz of this and prev unit (if there are)
  public currentUnitQuiz: IQuiz;
  public showQuiz: boolean;
  
  // .. more properties


  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      private userProgressService: UserProgressService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      // save this course id from course-detail and get http request from the service
      this.courseId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("courseId"));
      this.getCourse(this.courseId);
    }
    
  // Get course detail by id
  getCourse(id: number) {
      this.courseService.getCourse(id).subscribe(
          course => {
            this.course = course;
            
            // .. more code

            if (this.route.snapshot.firstChild.data.type == 'quiz') {
              this.getQuiz(this.currentUnitPos);
            }
          },
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
      }
      
      getQuiz(currentUnitPosition: number) {
      // .. more code
        this.showQuiz = true;
        this.currentUnitQuiz = this.course.units.find(u => u.position ===
        currentUnitPosition).quiz;
      }
 }
```

EDIT: added more code so it'll be clear. I get the same error when I try to access the length, but I also can print and get a number so I don't know what's the problem.

child ts:

```js
export class CourseQuizComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() quiz: IQuiz;
  
  // 1 = show the first page. 2 = show questions page. 0 = show neither
  public currentQuestion: IQuestion;
  public currentIndex: number;
  public currentUnit: number;
  public userAnswers: number[] = [];
  public correctAnswers: number;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("length in child: ", this.quiz.questions.length); // **NOT** undefined
    this.restartQuiz();
  }
  
    restartQuiz() {
    this.currentUnit = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('unitId');
    this.correctAnswers = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < this.quiz.questions.length; i++) {
      this.userAnswers[i] = 0;
    }

    this.getCurrentQuestion(0);
  }

}
```

interfaces:

```js
export interface IQuiz {
  id: number;
  name: number;
  unit_id: number;
  unit_position: number;
  questions: IQuestion[];
}

export interface IQuestion {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  quiz_id: number;
  position: number;
  question: string;
  answer1: string;
  answer2: string;
  answer3: string;
  answer4: string;
  correct: number;
  selected: number;
}
```

Comment: And where do you try to access the length property where it is undefined?

Comment: in the child, but I got the length in the console, it printed 2 and a line after it printed this error. I'll add a screenshot

Comment: at quiz-course component add ? before length like this quiz?.questions?.length in the html

Comment: Go to `IQuiz` class, assuming that `questions` is an array, check if it is initialized properly (example, questions = [])

Comment: questions is defined like that: questions: IQuestion[]; and I defined IQuestions too. I added the interfaces now

Comment: Show how you try to access it in the child component.

Comment: `and I get this error` <= show the code where the error is occurring.

Comment: it say that in the line when I print the value but It is printing the value

Comment: No, the stack trace states it occurs in method `restartQuiz`. Show that code.

Comment: I added it. I'm doing the same thing and try to access the length of the questions array, but also I get the length in the console from console.log

Comment: you have to init your quiz variable in the parent component

Comment: I know that I have values in the parent component because I tried to print it and I got value, and also I get the value in the child when I print with console.log, so it's weird that I get this error when I get the data with console.log

Comment: do you get currentUnitQuiz from an observable subscription?

Comment: yes and I see the data I get in the parent component. There's a lot of irrelevant code there but I'll edit the question and add the relevant code from parent ts

Comment: delete subscribe block and use Async pipe to avoid undefined case <quiz-course [quiz]="currentUnitQuizObservable | async"></quiz-course>

Comment: didn't work, now I get this error: Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Any particular reason the quiz is type IQuiz, and not type Quiz that implements the interface?

Answer (score 1):

this is an input to the child and so my best bet to avoid these undefined issue, use onchanges lifehook.

```
 import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

export class CourseQuizComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   for (const prop of Object.keys(changes)) {
    const chng = changes[prop];
    if (prop === 'quiz') {
      this.quiz = chng.currentValue;
      // use this quiz variable in the restartQuiz() 
    }
  }
 }
 ngOnInit() {
   this.restartQuiz();
  }
}
```

try this and let me know if this works.

Comment: it doesn't work unfortunately. I need to call restartQuiz when the component start it's life so I need to change that too and call it in ngOnChanges? what about the html file that contains the data from @Input?

Comment: You mentioned you need to call restartQuiz() in oninit(). That  doesnt change. Do not call restartQuiz() in onchanges. but intialize your quiz input variable in onchanges(). 

simply to put, Since its a child component, onchanges will make sure the input varibale will have the latest value once the child is loaded.

edited the answer to avoid misunderstandings.